# MediaPlayer OnCompletionListener causes error

Tags: android, audio, nullpointerexception, media-player

In my app I created a class to handle playing sound, it's called SoundPlayer and extends AsyncTask to load sound files seperately from main thread. It looks like this:

```
public class SoundPlayer extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> implements
        OnCompletionListener {

    private Integer[] soundIDs = {};
    private ArrayList<MediaPlayer> sound_player;
    // private MediaPlayer[] sound_player;
    private Context context;
    private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "SoundPlayer";
    private Timer timer;
    private Activity activity;

    public SoundPlayer(Integer[] soundIDs, Context context, Activity activity) {
        this.soundIDs = soundIDs;
        this.context = context;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        sound_player = new ArrayList<MediaPlayer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < soundIDs.length; i++) {
            MediaPlayer temp = new MediaPlayer();
            temp = MediaPlayer.create(context, soundIDs[i]);
            sound_player.add(temp);
            sound_player.get(i).setOnCompletionListener(SoundPlayer.this);
        }
        return null;
    }



    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        Log.e(DEBUG_TAG, "comp");

    }
}
```

And I run it from main activity this way:

```
soundplayer = new SoundPlayer(soundIDs, this, this);
    soundplayer.execute("");
```

Everything works fine when I run appliaction on my Samsung Galaxy Gio, but when I run it on Galaxy S2 it's not working. I noticed that the problem is in that line:

```
sound_player.get(i).setOnCompletionListener(SoundPlayer.this);
```

without that everything works (on both devices), however I have to set OnCompletionListsner so what's wrong ? I have also tried doing it this way:

```
sound_player.get(i).setOnCompletionListener((OnCompletionListener) context);
```

and letting my main activity to implement onCompletionListener method but it wasn't working also. Here's the LogCat:

```
    06-18 16:15:27.835 W/MediaPlayer(20250): info/warning (1, 44)
06-18 16:15:27.865 W/MediaPlayer(20250): info/warning (1, 44)
06-18 16:15:27.900 W/MediaPlayer(20250): info/warning (1, 44)
06-18 16:15:27.905 I/MediaPlayer(20250): Info (1,44)
06-18 16:15:27.905 I/MediaPlayer(20250): Info (1,44)
06-18 16:15:27.905 I/MediaPlayer(20250): Info (1,44)
06-18 16:15:27.950 W/MediaPlayer(20250): info/warning (1, 44)
06-18 16:15:27.990 W/MediaPlayer(20250): info/warning (1, 44)
06-18 16:15:28.005 I/MediaPlayer(20250): Info (1,44)
06-18 16:15:28.005 I/MediaPlayer(20250): Info (1,44)
06-18 16:15:28.035 W/MediaPlayer(20250): info/warning (1, 44)
06-18 16:15:28.035 I/MediaPlayer(20250): Info (1,44)
06-18 16:15:28.060 W/MediaPlayer(20250): info/warning (1, 44)
06-18 16:15:28.060 I/MediaPlayer(20250): Info (1,44)
06-18 16:15:28.085 W/MediaPlayer(20250): info/warning (1, 26)
06-18 16:15:28.085 I/MediaPlayer(20250): Info (1,26)
06-18 16:15:28.085 E/MediaPlayer(20250): error (1, -17)
06-18 16:15:28.085 E/MediaPlayer(20250): Error (1,-17)
06-18 16:15:28.090 D/MediaPlayer(20250): create failed:
06-18 16:15:28.090 D/MediaPlayer(20250): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
06-18 16:15:28.090 D/MediaPlayer(20250):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
06-18 16:15:28.090 D/MediaPlayer(20250):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:691)
06-18 16:15:28.090 D/MediaPlayer(20250):    at com.artostolab.scaryringtones.SoundPlayer.doInBackground(SoundPlayer.java:36)
06-18 16:15:28.090 D/MediaPlayer(20250):    at com.artostolab.scaryringtones.SoundPlayer.doInBackground(SoundPlayer.java:1)
06-18 16:15:28.090 D/MediaPlayer(20250):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
06-18 16:15:28.090 D/MediaPlayer(20250):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
06-18 16:15:28.090 D/MediaPlayer(20250):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
06-18 16:15:28.090 D/MediaPlayer(20250):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
06-18 16:15:28.090 D/MediaPlayer(20250):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
06-18 16:15:28.090 D/MediaPlayer(20250):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

and

```
    06-18 16:25:10.330 W/MediaPlayer(21988): info/warning (1, 26)
06-18 16:25:10.330 E/MediaPlayer(21988): error (1, -17)
06-18 16:25:10.335 I/MediaPlayer(21988): Info (1,26)
06-18 16:25:10.335 E/MediaPlayer(21988): Error (1,-17)
06-18 16:25:10.335 D/MediaPlayer(21988): create failed:
06-18 16:25:10.335 D/MediaPlayer(21988): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
06-18 16:25:10.335 D/MediaPlayer(21988):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
06-18 16:25:10.335 D/MediaPlayer(21988):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:691)
06-18 16:25:10.335 D/MediaPlayer(21988):    at com.artostolab.scaryringtones.SoundPlayer.doInBackground(SoundPlayer.java:38)
06-18 16:25:10.335 D/MediaPlayer(21988):    at com.artostolab.scaryringtones.SoundPlayer.doInBackground(SoundPlayer.java:1)
06-18 16:25:10.335 D/MediaPlayer(21988):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
06-18 16:25:10.335 D/MediaPlayer(21988):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
06-18 16:25:10.335 D/MediaPlayer(21988):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
06-18 16:25:10.335 D/MediaPlayer(21988):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
06-18 16:25:10.335 D/MediaPlayer(21988):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
06-18 16:25:10.335 D/MediaPlayer(21988):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
06-18 16:25:10.335 W/dalvikvm(21988): threadid=8: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001e578)
06-18 16:25:10.340 E/AndroidRuntime(21988): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
06-18 16:25:10.340 E/AndroidRuntime(21988): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
06-18 16:25:10.340 E/AndroidRuntime(21988):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
06-18 16:25:10.340 E/AndroidRuntime(21988):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
06-18 16:25:10.340 E/AndroidRuntime(21988):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
06-18 16:25:10.340 E/AndroidRuntime(21988):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
06-18 16:25:10.340 E/AndroidRuntime(21988):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
06-18 16:25:10.340 E/AndroidRuntime(21988):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
06-18 16:25:10.340 E/AndroidRuntime(21988):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
06-18 16:25:10.340 E/AndroidRuntime(21988):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
06-18 16:25:10.340 E/AndroidRuntime(21988): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-18 16:25:10.340 E/AndroidRuntime(21988):     at com.artostolab.scaryringtones.SoundPlayer.doInBackground(SoundPlayer.java:40)
06-18 16:25:10.340 E/AndroidRuntime(21988):     at com.artostolab.scaryringtones.SoundPlayer.doInBackground(SoundPlayer.java:1)
06-18 16:25:10.340 E/AndroidRuntime(21988):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
06-18 16:25:10.340 E/AndroidRuntime(21988):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
06-18 16:25:10.340 E/AndroidRuntime(21988):     ... 4 more
06-18 16:25:10.345 E/        (2696): Dumpstate > /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
06-18 16:25:10.345 W/ActivityManager(2696):   Force finishing activity com.artostolab.scaryringtones/.MainList
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution on my own, don't know why but setting onCompletionListener inside doInBackground method causes null pointer exception on some devices, so I figured out to set OnCompletionListner outside from this method, for example when you want to play sound and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I think what is happening is that your call `MediaPlayer.create(context, soundIDs[i]);` has failed (see the stack trace - "java.io.IOException: Prepare failed") so temp is null.

Creating many MediaPlayer instances might be the root cause. I have an app that plays a sequence of individual sound samples and I create my instances on the fly.

Comment: But it's not happening when I don't use this line: "sound_player.get(i).setOnCompletionListener(SoundPlayer.this);'
Without it everything works fine so I think the problem is not in creating many MediaPlayer instances

Comment: Yes. But (assuming my theory is correct) you've just put a null value into the array, so sound_player.get(i) will return null, and you are calling setOnCompletionListener on a null object, hence the NPE...

Comment: It would be corrected but I tested it and tried to play a sound using this array and it worked fine, so I think it's not the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try to place `setOnCompletionListener` with `onClickCompletion` before `On Create` method. Then call `onClickCOmpletion` after `start()` it works for me

```
/**
 * This listener gets triggered when the {@link MediaPlayer} has completed
 * playing the audio file.
 */
private MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener mCompletionListener = new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        // Now that the sound file has finished playing, release the media player resources.
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Finish sound", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        mediaPlayer.release();
    }
};
```